# hot to syntax postman header for hashed result

Tags: postman

I need to hash my credentials to get access to api like this  sha2(app-secret:SALT:timestamp)

I set this in the  header as authtoken which should have this hashed value  `auth-token: api.hashify.net/hash/sha256/{{appSecret}}:{{SALT}}:{{timestamp}}`

Can you please advise if the usage is correct I mean if adding thisapi.hashify.net/hash/sha256/ in front of the keys will get me what I need

Answer (score 0):

it will be send just as a string it won't call to that endpoint , so instead call that endpoint in pre- request script, and store response value to a variable and use it in auth header :

```
// Example with a plain string URL
pm.sendRequest(`https://api.hashify.net/hash/sha256/${pm.environment.get('appSecret')}:${pm.environment.get('SALT')}:${pm.environment.get('timestamp')}`, (error, response) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
  console.log(response.json());  // or response.text() if parse error
  }
});
```

inside else statement write logic to get the value and use `pm.environment.set("auth-token",value)`

now in header `auth-token:{{auth-token}}`